# HP envy dv6 overheating after installing ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hp, overheating, temperature

I recently had a problem with Windows 8.1, a kernel crash or something, so I installed Ubuntu 15.04.

Since I installed it, the temperature of the CPU is ~57°C, I got the stats using `tlp`.

Any advise on how to reduce the temperature?

Screen of my config:

[image]

And I have an nvidia GT635M graphic card

EDIT:
`lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 181b
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 181b
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

I know it may seem a duplicate question, but I didn't find an answered one that is similar to mine.

Comment: Nvidia driver is not installed. Please run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime` and post output.

Comment: I don't really see a difference

Comment: I asked output of installation command, not same command. Driver is not installed, I want to find out why.

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry, here it is: http://pastebin.com/FLS6hnAs

Comment: Now reboot and it should work.

Comment: thank you a lot! I switched to Intel finally, hope it will not overheat any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both video adapters work at the same time. That is why the computer overheats.

Install Nvidia drivers from System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Or from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

And reboot.

You will be able to switch adapters in Nvidia application.

Comment: the gui is very bad, I cannot find out how to switch the drivers, could you guide me please?

Comment: @Mark he said how to using the Terminal - press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to access a terminal.

Comment: After I installed it there wasn't an option for switching between graphic cards

Comment: Please add to your question output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just added it

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with my dv6 overheating constantly no matter what drivers I used. Ended up patching a power wire from usb +5v to red fan power wire to keep fan up to speed. Spent days trying to find a software solution for fan speed,but that was the best I could do. Not elegant, but effective. For my laptop anyway.